# npm - module not found if run with docker

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, npm

I'm trying to run my vue application with docker. After updating npm packages locally, I get the following error:

```
-  Building for production...
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error8:17:57 AM

This relative module was not found:

* ../internals/a-function in ./node_modules/core-js/internals/new-promise-capability.js
 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
```

Under Windows, everything works fine. I already tried to add the latest core-js module and to restore the package.json to a stable state, but without success. I don't know what I am missing.

My Dockerfile:

```
# develop stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as develop-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY app/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY app/. .

# build stage
FROM develop-stage as build-stage
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 90
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.6",
    "@growthbunker/vuedarkmode": "^0.5.56",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "colormap": "^2.3.2",
    "core-js": "^3.18.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "prismjs": "^1.25.0",
    "pvw-visualizer": "^3.2.2",
    "splitpanes": "^2.3.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-json-editor": "^1.4.3",
    "vue-json-pretty": "^1.8.1",
    "vue-numeral-filter": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-numerals": "^4.0.6",
    "vue-plotly": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-prism-editor": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-remote-component": "^1.4.0",
    "vue-vtk-js": "^1.1.6",
    "vuescroll": "^4.17.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.10",
    "yaml-loader": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.14",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.14",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.14",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.19.1",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.4.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: to see detailed error, remove "npm install" from your Dockerfile, create image and container, connect your container's bash and there type "npm install".  It gives you far more specific error logs.

Comment: Great idea @y.selimdogan , I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

Removing the build stage, somehow fixed it:

```
# develop stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as develop-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY app/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY app/. .

# # build stage
# FROM develop-stage as build-stage
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=develop-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 90
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```